# Union or better way SQL query joining to result sets with similar tables

Tags: sql

I have a query where I am joining two data sets using union, with a lot of similar table joins. The only difference between the two queries are the two relation tables `ection_view_reltns & element_section_reltns` and `graph_view_reltns & graph_element_reltns`  They start their joins on cv.orig_charting_view_id.

I would appreciate some help and was wondering if there a better way to write this to enhance the query performance?

```
select cv.orig_charting_view_id, cvt.view_name, cvt.view_label, cv.version, ce.orig_charting_element_id, ce.version, cet.element_name, cet.element_label, ce.element_type, ce.element_type_meaning, ce.beg_effective_dt_tm
from charting_views cv
inner join charting_view_translations cvt ON cvt.charting_view_id = cv.charting_view_id
inner join section_view_reltns scr ON scr.orig_charting_view_id = cv.orig_charting_view_id and scr.charting_view_version = cv.version
inner join element_section_reltns esr ON esr.orig_charting_section_id = scr.orig_charting_section_id and esr.charting_section_version = scr.charting_section_version
inner join charting_elements ce ON ce.orig_charting_element_id = esr.orig_charting_element_id and ce.version = esr.charting_element_version
inner join charting_element_translations cet ON cet.charting_element_id = ce.charting_element_id
where cv.end_effective_dt_tm > NOW() and cv.status = 2
and cet.locale='en-US'
and ce.end_effective_dt_tm > NOW() and ce.status = 2
union
select cv.orig_charting_view_id, cvt.view_name, cvt.view_label, cv.version, ce.orig_charting_element_id, ce.version, cet.element_name, cet.element_label, ce.element_type, ce.element_type_meaning, ce.beg_effective_dt_tm
from charting_views cv
inner join charting_view_translations cvt ON cvt.charting_view_id = cv.charting_view_id
inner join graph_view_reltns gvr ON gvr.orig_charting_view_id = cv.orig_charting_view_id
inner join graph_element_reltns ger ON ger.graph_id = gvr.orig_graph_id and ger.graph_version = gvr.graph_version
inner join charting_elements ce ON ce.orig_charting_element_id = ger.element_id and ce.version = ger.charting_element_version
inner join charting_element_translations cet ON cet.charting_element_id = ce.charting_element_id
where cv.end_effective_dt_tm > NOW() and cv.status = 2
and ce.end_effective_dt_tm > NOW() and ce.status = 2
and cet.locale='en-US'
;
```

Comment: Often you should choose `union all`, not `union`,   to enhance the query performance, and after enclose in query with a `group by` if necessary.

Comment: You could probably combine this into a single query using outer joins for the differences and some additional filtering.